# How do I force a rails ActiveRecord string column to only accept strings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Post` class with a `title:string` field

```
post = Post.create!
#=> Post created
post.title = "foo"
post.save! 
# success
post.title = 1
post.save! 
# succeeds, but I want it to throw a type mismatch exception
```

How do I get the last save! to throw a type mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is a duck-typed language and doesn't have type mismatches. If an object responds to `to_s`, Rails will call `to_s` on it and put it into a string field.

It sounds like what you really want is to validate the format of the value you're putting into the field (is the string `"2"` a valid value?), which is what `validates_format_of` is for. For example, if you want to ensure that the value has at least one non-digit character, you could do this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_format_of :title, with: /\D/
end
```

Of course, you very well may want to customize that regex a bit more.

If you really can't stand duck-typing and want to make sure nothing but a true String goes into that column, you can override `title=`:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def title=(value)
    throw "`title' must be a String" unless value.is_a?(String)
    super
  end
end
```

Note that this won't be invoked when you do e.g. `post[:title] = ...` or `post.write_attribute(:title, ...)` but it should cover 95% of situations.

Comment: I don't think that custom validation will work, because the integer has already been coerced into a string before save is called.

Comment: I think you're right, Anand. I've updated my answer with another method that should work.

Comment: It seems like overriding title= is the best option in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This really runs against the grain of what Ruby is all about. If it's a string column, the database layer will take care of rendering that value as a string and saving it.

The concept of a type is different in Ruby than in other languages. Generally if an object supports `to_s` then it's considered to be *string-enough* to use, the basic tenet of [Duck Typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

If you pass in something that can't be rendered as a string you will get an exception. For example:

```
post.title = Post.find(5)
```

If you're looking to ensure your fields are not numerical, you should add a validation that enforces a particular format.

Comment: I realize that ruby is loosely typed, but one could argue that ActiveRecord is strongly typed. And  it is Active Record that is calling the shots here, since post.title is of type String, no matter what you pass in, unlike ruby which would have changed the type from String to FixNum when an integer is assigned.

Comment: Don't confuse aggressively converted with strongly typed.

Comment: I meant strongly typed relative to ruby

Comment: I'd still advise steering away from this sort of enforcement. Every library I've used that does this sort of thing comes across as arrogant, extremely annoying, and not worth dealing with. Ruby isn't Java. It's got a much more casual approach to these things that, if embraced, makes life a lot less stressful. If you pass in an object that can be rendered as a string, and the receiver needs a string, then the receiver should be able to figure it out. Strict validation and comprehensive unit tests should verify what is and isn't allowed, not strict class comparisons.

Comment: I completely agree that checking like that in most cases is annoying. I have a need to test the type of the value being assigned in a very specific, somewhat uncommon scenario, and checking the incoming type is essential in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A new gem has been created to help [validate types in rails](https://github.com/yez/validates_type) and an [explanatory blog post](http://jakeyesbeck.com/2015/05/10/validates-type/) exists to answer more of the "why" it was created in the first place.

With this library your code would simple be:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_type :title, :string
end
```

This will throw an exception when an integer is assigned to `title` instead of quietly casting the `title` to a string and saving it.

Comment: As mentioned in other comments, the validation is fired at save time, but the assignment and conversion happens before that (`post.title=1`). So, this validator will not help.

Comment: That is not the case with this validator. This one validates the type of the attribute before coercion. It is explained in the post that I have provided. It's entire purpose is to make sure your data is actually the type you want, not the type it gets casted into by your ORM.

Comment: Nice.you may want to rename the gem and method to something else (like ensures_type),  since all validates are expected to run only on save.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the exact question, if you want to make sure that only objects of class String are saved to the field, you should add the following custom validation.

```
  validate :must_be_string

  def must_be_string
    errors.add(:base, 'The field must be String') unless title.class == String
  end
```

Comment: `title.class == String` will fail if `title` is an instance of a subclass of String, e.g. ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom validator.

```
validates :title, type: String
```

and then:

```
class TypeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add attribute, (options[:message] || "is not of class #{options[:with]}") unless
      value.class == options[:with]
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think that will work, because the integer has already been coerced into a string before save/validate  is called.